# VTK - Unstructured Grid: Change order of points/Labeling Points

Tags: grid, mesh, vtk

I have probems converting an existing mesh from to vtk legacy format.

VTK-Unstructured Grids have the following structure:

```
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_ GRID 
POINTS n dataType 
p0x p0y p0z 
p1x p1y p1z 

... 
p (n-1) x p (n-1) y p (n-1) z 

CELLS n size 
numPoints0 ,i, j, k, l,... 
numPoints1 ,i, j, k, l,... 
numPoints2 ,i, j, k, l,... 
... 
numPointsn-1 ,i, j, k, l,... 
Simple Legacy Formats 5 

CELL_ TYPES n 
...
```

The cells are specified by their connectivity points IDs and their type. 
It seems that point ID always corresponds to the order of the points specified in the block before.

Is there a way to label the points in abitrary order? 
For instance the first entries in the point block should correspond to index 3 instead of index 0.

I would really appreciate your help! TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy VTK format does not support that.
You will have to write a script that will reorder your points in the `POINTS` section accordingly.

Moreover, I don't see such a capability even in the more flexible XML-based VTU formats. So, I would suggest:

1. Write a script that is going to reorder the points in [0, N-1] in the way they are going to be referenced for connectivity in the `CELLS` section.
2. Or vice versa, write a script that will renumber the connectivity information in the `CELLS` section accordingly.
3. (*optional*) Consider switching to XML-based formats anyway, as they are more flexible, have better-supported libraries (IMHO) for IO, and allow for proper parallel IO, random access, and portable data compression.